# Подскажите в чём ошибка? Не обрабатывается bot.callback_query_handler

Tags: python, telebot

Помогите ,пожалуйста, не обрабатывается bot.callback_query_handler, список с кнопками не появляется. В чём моя ошибка? Буду признательна за помощь!

```
import os
import mimetypes
import telebot
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from pathlib import Path

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Открыть обращение', callback_data='opennew'))
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Закрыть обращение', callback_data='closeold'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что хотите сделать?'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def start_mes(call):

     if call.data == 'opennew':
        markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Колбасный цех', callback_data='Колбасный'))
        markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Столярный цех', callback_data='Столярный'))

     if call.data == 'closeold':
        bot.copy_message('3293122', message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        bot.reply_to(message, "Сообщение отправлено. \nДля возврата в главное меню нажмите/start")


while True:
    try:
        bot.polling()
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Начните с удаления абсолютно вредного `except: continue` чтобы иметь возможность прочитать тексты возможных ошибок

Comment: Потому что вы этот маркап не отправляете в `if call.data == 'opennew'`, а только делаете. Отправьте сообщение по типу `bot.send_message(..., reply_markup=markup)`